# How to obtain Edittext values from dynamically created editttexts using a single button

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am splitting a string and putting the result in edittexts using a loop so that the user can edit the data.thereafter he can  save  all the data in 
the edittexts by just pressing  the final button.Problem is i don't know how to get each value from the edittext when he pressses the save button.this is my code:

```
  EditText etstringone,etstringtwo; 
  Button btn_save;
  btnsave=new Button(this);

  String mystring="somevalue";
  String del="\\|";
  String[] splitResult = mystring.split(del); 

  for (String e : splitResult)
    {

     etstringone=new EditText(this);
     etstringtwo=new EditText(this);

    etstringone.setText(splitResult[0]);
    etstringtwo.setText(splitResult[1]);

    mylayout.addView(etstringone);
    mylayout.addView(etstringtwo);
    }
  mylayout.addView(btnsave);

  btnsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // how to get each value from the edittexts and output each to logcat,,i'll do the saving  and the rest

        }
    });
```

how do i go about this?thanks.

NB:emphasis on using a single button to get all the data,i managed to do a scenario for apppending a new save button each time the 
        loop runs but its not neat.

Answer (score 0):

The edit texts are dynamically created, but you can still access the object. Either cache a reference to the edit texts or walk the child-views of your "mylayout".

EDIT

From your code, you declare

```
EditText etstringone,etstringtwo;
```

You instantiate them

```
 etstringone=new EditText(this);
 etstringtwo=new EditText(this);
```

Now I don't know the scope of this (are they local vars, class/member vars?) if class vars, you can reference them in the

```
btnsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // how to get each value from the edittexts and output each to logcat,,i'll do the saving  and the rest

    }
});
```

body. eg

```
btnsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String e1 = etstringone..getText().toString();

    }
});
```

Comment: how exactly do i go about this?

Comment: already tried that,but that only gives the last set of values from the edittexts i.e if the split array has more than one value,,i want to get the dat from each of the edittexts

Comment: than put each of the edit texts you create in to a list, make sure the list is class scope, and iterate over the list in the onclick action.